# Error NoClassDefFoundError: sun/net/smtp/SmtpClient

Tags: java

I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundError` while approving my document.

I have added `smtp jar` file, `mail.jar` and i am using `jboss 6`.

I am not able to find what is the issue if any one knows kindly let me know.

Comment: Have you placed it in WEB-INF\lib ?

Comment: What is in your jboss deployment structure xml ? Have you added the dependency ?

Comment: Provide more information about your environment please. Surely you are missing the needed library in the classpath at runtime

Comment: hi, yes i have added in WEB-INF\lib

Comment: Hi, i am sending mail while approving the documnet .Error is generating in my console NoClassDefFoundError: sun/net/smtp/SmtpClient

Comment: which jdk/jre are you using?

Comment: i am using jdk 1.6  and jboss 6 as my application server